# DataGridView cell text and cell value

Tags: c#, text, datagridview, cell

I have a problem with a readonly C# Winform DataGridView.

I have a `DataSource` for a `DataTable` and assign it to `DataGridView1.DataSource`. I want to display cell text by cell value without changing the `DataSource`.

**Ex:**

```
cell value=1 => cell display text="one", 
cell value=2 => cell display text="two"
```

I want that, if I get:

```
DataGridView1.Rows[rowIndex].Cells[columnIndex].Value
```

Then it must be `1` (or `2`, or `3`) not "one" (or "two", or "three").

Comment: So you're storing text representations of numbers in your DataTable, but you want to display the numeric representation in the DataGridView? Is that what you're saying? Can you provide some more insight as to why you have to do this, and not just have the numbers stored in the data table?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can use CellFormatting event handler.

```
private void DataGridView1_CellFormatting(object sender,
    DataGridViewCellFormattingEventArgs e)
{
    DataGridView dgv = (DataGridView)sender;
    if (dgv.Columns[e.ColumnIndex].Name == "TargetColumnName" &&
        e.RowIndex >= 0 &&
        dgv["TargetColumnName", e.RowIndex].Value is int)
    {
        switch ((int)dgv["TargetColumnName", e.RowIndex].Value)
        {
            case 1:
                e.Value = "one";
                e.FormattingApplied = true;
                break;
            case 2:
                e.Value = "two";
                e.FormattingApplied = true;
                break;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! This is the full answer for me

Comment: How can I implement it in radfatagridview?

Answer (score 3):

my solutions is to put the value in DataGridViewCell.Tag property.

Like this :

```
 DataGridView1.Rows[rowIndex].Cells[columnIndex].Tag = 1;
```

Comment: you can't do this, it's very manual. when assign `DataSource`, you must assign `Tag` again.

Comment: Just a comment - the tag can be data bound as well. But the selected answer is the best way to do this, IMO..

Answer (score 0):

you can create class for it:

```
public class Item
{
    public int Id { get; }
    public string Name { get; }

    public Item(string name, int id)
    {
        Id = id;
        Name = name;
    }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return Name;
    }
}
```

Then

```
 DataGridView1.Rows[rowIndex].Cells[columnIndex]=new Item("One", 1);
```